# removing duplicates from Sphinx Search based on 1 column

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have one table which I need to do a search on, this table is formed through a `join` between 2 other tables.
`ThinkingSphinx::Index` is defined on table `posts`, my `posts_index.rb` looks something like this:

```
join 'LEFT JOIN threads on posts.id = threads.id'
indexes 'posts.text', as: posts_text
indexes 'threads.text', as: threads_text
```

and my tables:

```
threads
| id | text       |
| 0  | test title |
| 1  | foo  bar   |

posts
| id | parent | text
| 0  | 0      | some stuff
| 1  | 0      | more stuff
```

What I need to do is to perform a sphinx search on both the `thread.text` and the `posts.text`. Say I do a search on the word `stuff`, this comes back

```
thread.id | posts.id | thread.text | posts.text |
0         | 0        | test title  | some stuff |
0         | 1        | test title  | more stuff |
```

this is what I need, but if I do a search on the word `test`, this comes back

```
thread.id | posts.id | thread.text | posts.text |
0         | 0        | test title  | some stuff |
0         | 1        | test title  | more stuff |
```

this is NOT what I want, as you can see there is an extra unnecessary row returned, in this case I only want the first row. I cannot do a `group_by` because one thread can have many posts that may/may not contain the search term, I still need to return all of those `posts` that are hit. The only time when I dont want a certain duplicate result is if the search term is ONLY found in the thread title. For various reasons I cannot just write a filter after the sphinx search, it has to be written into the query.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way to do this would be to arrange that the thread.text column is blank on all but one post (eg the first), that way a keyword match against the thread title can only ever match against one post.

(but you then can't get matches, where some words match the title, and some match the post text, for anything but the first post)

... also not sure exactly how to arrange for this in ThinkingSphinx.

Answer (score 0):

not really a solution but I ended up just adding another index and removed the title field from the other index.